# How to make hollow Graphics3D?

Tags: graphics3d, code-request, 3d-printing

I keep seeing a notebook to use of *Mathematica* as a 3D Printing tool (e.g.: [this link](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/7846/LucBarthelet.zip?file_id=7439)). In the notebook on slide 8/11, we find these pictures:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I'd like to design it as such that, but I don't know how to create the above examples. 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried emailing the author of the notebook?

Comment: Interesting question!
It will require something along this lines, if you are into relying on bitmap patterns:

1. `EdgeDetect` for the pattern image
2. Extraction of the contours, possibly using `ImageValuePositions` and constructing closed paths from that data.
3. Creating a hollowed region (hollow within some boundary you chose).
4. Deforming the region in 3D, using e.g. a 2D-Gaussian.
5. Extruding the deformed region by the target thickness you desire.
6. Constructing something of the shape by translation and rotation, e.g. something like the cube you mentioned.

As I said: Interesting!

Comment: Then again, you could start out with your own regions, e.g. a disk, rectangle, superellipse or whatever, and transform/rotate to follow along a e.g. logarithmic spiral, putting all this into a `BoundaryRegion` and continue with the steps from my last comment, saving you the hassle of dealing with pixelated input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a `Graphics3D` object from that file (4th object down from the top of slide 8)

[image]

(which I'm calling p) we can reconstruct your graphic as follows:

```
z = Union@
   Cases[p[[1]], {x_Real, y_Real, z_Real} :> {{x, y}, 
      z}, {0, \[Infinity]}];
d2 = DiscretizeGraphics@
   Graphics@
    Replace[p[[1]], {x_Real, y_Real, z_Real} :> {x, 
       y}, {0, \[Infinity]}];
b = BoundaryMesh[
   RegionProduct[d2, MeshRegion[{{0}, {1}}, Line[{1, 2}]]]];
iz = Quiet@Interpolation[z];
len = RegionBounds[b][[1, 2]];
mc = MeshCoordinates[
    b] /. {{x_, y_, 0.} :> {x, y, iz[x, y]}, {x_, y_, 1.} :> {x, y, 
      iz[x, y] + 1}};
mr = MeshRegion[mc, MeshCells[b, 2]];
m2 = Show[mr, 
   TransformedRegion[
    TransformedRegion[mr, RotationTransform[Pi, {1, 0, 0}]], 
    TranslationTransform[{0, 0, len*2}]]];
out = Show[m2, 
  Graphics3D[
   GeometricTransformation[
    GeometricTransformation[
     m2[[1]], {RotationMatrix[90 Degree, {0, 1, 0}]}], 
    TranslationTransform[{-50.8, 0, 50.8}]]], 
  Graphics3D[
   GeometricTransformation[
    GeometricTransformation[
     m2[[1]], {RotationMatrix[90 Degree, {1, 0, 0}]}], 
    TranslationTransform[{0, 50.8, 50.8}]]]]
```

[image]

Comment: I really really appreciate your help!

Comment: @XiangLi You're welcome :)